# \includegraphics renders my pdf at the right side of the page (exceeds page bounds)

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages

I have a pdf that I'd like to insert in my document.
When using graphicx or pdfpages the pdf is rendered like this:

In the pdf itself, the drawing are pretty centered.

What can I do to centralize this?

[image: Preview]

Comment: Most likely, you're image has  lot of white space. Try to use `[scale=0.3]` as an option to `\includegraphics`

Comment: if it's just one page, you can try using `pdfcrop` to get rid of extra white space.

Comment: Try `\fbox\includegraphics{}}` to see the bounding box of your graphic.

Comment: A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem would help us to help you.